# Unhandled event loop exception while I try to add a second Activity

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm new to Android app development. I'm using Eclipse v4.6 (Neon) for this. When I try to add a second Activity to my project, an error occurs which says:

> Unhandled event LoopException occurred.

Other details of the error are:

The details of the log file are:

```
Unhandled event loop exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

The details of the log file are:

```
Plug In: org.eclipse.ui
Severity: error
Exception Stack Trace:
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFileNatives.internalGetFileInfoW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFileNatives.fetchFileInfo(LocalFileNatives.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFileHandler.fetchFileInfo(LocalFileHandler.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFileNativesManager.fetchFileInfo(LocalFileNativesManager.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.fetchInfo(LocalFile.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.fetchInfo(FileStore.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.fastIsSynchronized(FileSystemResourceManager.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.isSynchronized(FileSystemResourceManager.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.isSynchronized(Resource.java:1446)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContentDescription(File.java:257)
```

How do I fix these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android Studio there is a AndroidManifest.xml file which all activities are registered in. Maybe you should register your activities in Eclipse as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an activity with your IDE tools, not by yourself. In Android Studio you can easily right click on the project folder → *New* → *Android activity*.

In Eclipse you can click on the new project button and choose *Android Activity* (below *Android Application Project*).